# Splitting up number by certain amount

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop, octave

I'm trying to split up numbers by a given value (4000) and have the numbers placed in an array

Example: 
max value given is: **8202**

So the split_array should be split by 4000 unless it gets to the end and it's less than 4000
in which case it just goes to the end.

```
start_pos, end_pos
0,4000
4001,8001
8002,8202

so the first row in the array would be
[0 4000]
second row would be
[4001 8001]
third row would be 
[8002 8202]
```

please note that the max value can change from **(8202)** to be any other number like **(16034)** but never a decimal
How can I go about doing this using matlab / octave

Comment: In your example, is the the first row `[0 4000]` or `0:4000`? Are you just include the start and end or everything between too?

Comment: @horchler  the first row is [0 4000]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should produce what you want

```
n = 8202;
a = [0:4001:n; [4000:4001:n-1 n]]'
```

returns

```
a =
           0        4000
        4001        8001
        8002        8202
```